# How can I geometrically understand the fundamental group of the 1-skeleton of the unit cube?

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Consider the unit cube $I^3$. I'm aware that the 1-skeleton consists of all the edges of the cube and that the fundamental group is $\mathbb{Z} \star \mathbb{Z} \star \mathbb{Z}$, but I'm trying to understand how the cube deforms into the wedge sum of three circles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given a connected, finite graph (such as the 1-skeleton of your unit cube), the following operations do not change the homotopy type (left as an exercise):

1. Removing loose ends, i.e. collapsing edges that have a vertex to which no other edge is attached (that is, a vertex of valence one).
2. Collapsing an embedded edge, i.e. collapsing an edge whose two vertices/ends do not coincide, to a point. (small exercise: Why does this mean that the edge is embedded?)

These processes reduce the number of edges and vertices of a graph. In particular, we can reduce any graph of the given type to a graph with only a single vertex, i.e. a bouquet of circles, in this manner.

In your case, it will reduce the graph to a bouquet of 5 circles. This is probably most easily seen by actually drawing the graph and applying the above operations, making intermediate drawings after each step.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by valence one vertices or embedded edges. Can you please elaborate further. I've only just been introduced to CW complexes. Also, the 1-skeleton of $I^3$ does not have vertices of valence 1 if I'm understanding what you have written correctly

Comment: @Jordan That is correct---there are no valence 1 vertices in this case. The concept of valence is explained on the relevant wikipedia page, which should be easy for you to find.

Comment: Thanks, I drew the picture, I ended up getting the bouquet of circles. I wasn't aware that it was obtained by collapsing embedded edges.

Comment: How would I go about proving this? That collapsing embedded edges preserves fundamental group.

Comment: @Jordan one way to start is to show it for one of the edges of a square or triangle, by writing down an explicit homotopy that collapses an edge, and one that does the reverse. Then, you can argue why the general case is almost identical to the simple one you just did.